# Panel Data Time Series (Add TimeStamps with interpolated values)

Tags: python, pandas, panel

I have a panel dataset with missing time stamps including values for some identities in a dataframe.

```
Index      Identiy Value
2015-01-01   A      13
2017-01-01   A      14
2018-01-01   A      24 
2019-01-01   A      30
2015-01-01   B      10
2016-01-01   B      12
2017-01-01   B      18
2018-01-01   B      25 
2019-01-01   B      30
```

How is it possible to automatically check if certain time stamps (gaps) are missing and then creat a row with the interpolated value. Easier, how can i  add a row in the dataframe with the follwing info.

```
Index         Identity        Value
2016-0101         A         13,5 (Interpolated between the gap (13,5)
```

This should only be done to gaps with less then 6 missing points.

I understand the interpolate function but unforunately can not bed it into the creation of row.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GroupBy` with `resample` to yearly, so we add the missing years to our data per `Identity`, then `interpolate` and finally set your index to beginning of year with `pd.offsets.YearBegin`:

```
dfn = df.groupby('Identiy').apply(lambda x: x.resample('Y').first().interpolate(limit=5).ffill())

dfn.index = dfn.index.droplevel(0) - pd.offsets.YearBegin()

           Identiy  Value
2015-01-01       A   13.0
2016-01-01       A   13.5
2017-01-01       A   14.0
2018-01-01       A   24.0
2019-01-01       A   30.0
2015-01-01       B   10.0
2016-01-01       B   12.0
2017-01-01       B   18.0
2018-01-01       B   25.0
2019-01-01       B   30.0
```

Comment: Wo that looks great. How do you control that it is only done if the gap is maximal 5 time stamps. If the gap is bigger it should not be interpolated as i want to drop it. Thank you Erfan.